# How to check results of LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

In a WPF app I'd like to check if a return of a LINQ to SQL query contains some records, but my approach doesn't work:

```
        TdbDataContext context = new TdbDataContext();
        var sh = from p in context.Items where p.Selected == true select p;

        if (sh == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no Selected Items");
        }
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A linq query will never be null because it will always return an `IQueryable`. Try calling `sh.Any()` instead.

```
if (!sh.Any())
    MessageBox.Show("There are no Selected Items");
```

Comment: @IanR: `IQueryable` doesn't have a `Count` property. `Any()` is the correct answer.

Comment: @280Z28 - Sorry, my bad, I was thinking of the Count() extension method, but as someone else pointed out, this would enumerate the sequence.. +1 from me for Any(), anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var query = (from k in context.invis select k.invoice);
    if (query.Count() > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    //
```